# Merge two tables in Access which share same values

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm total newbie in Database management so please don't judge me. I had two XML files, which i did import into Access as tables. Now i have two tables (movies and movies1).
 `Movies table has fields: Title and Year.`
`Movies1 table has fields: Title and Genre.`
I want to merge this tables to create new one with fields: `Title, Year, Genre` but only for those that share same name. Is there anyway to do that? And if answer is "yes", then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` to get matching records from both Movies and Movies1 table like below (posted sample query is per SQL syntax and not specific to MS ACCESS syntax). You will have to correct the syntax if any as per `ms access`

```
select m.Title, m.Year, m1.Genre
from movies as m inner join
     movies1 as m1
     on m.title = m1.title
```

`m` and `m1` are `table alias` which are used for qualifying table column. Example: `m.title` saying that `title` column will be selected from `movies` table as well it increases ease of readability.

**EDIT:**

Try the query without table alias

```
select movies.Title, movies.Year, movies1.Genre
from movies inner join
     movies1 
     on movies.title = movies1.title
```

**EDIT1:**

if you want to insert the query result into a different/new table then the form is as below. See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more details.

```
INSERT INTO target [(field1[, field2[, …]])] [IN externaldatabase] 
SELECT [source.]field1[, field2[, …]     FROM tableexpression
```

In your case it should be

```
INSERT INTO processed_movie
 select m.Title, m.Year, m1.Genre
 from movies as m inner join
     movies1 as m1
     on m.title = m1.title
```

Comment: sir, i'm complete noob what does `m.` mean?

Comment: @Amal.A, see my answer carefully. I have already mentioned that the query is per normal SQL syntax and not specific to ACCESS. syntax error you will have to handle and that way you will learn.

Comment: @Amal.A, See edited again. try the edited query once. should work fine.

Comment: @Rahul . . . MS Access supports table aliases but you have to use `as`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thank you; I was actually searching that but couldn't find in Microsoft Office document. All the example provided used explicit table name. Anyways, edited my answer per your comment.

Comment: Since he's new, you might want to tell him how get that into the new table.

Comment: @AlvinThompson, that would be great!

Comment: @Amal.A - just use my solution

Comment: @Amal.A, See edited answer (`EDIT1` part) in case you want to insert the query result to a new table. Search in `Google` OR read through MSDN document .. you will find out the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Create the new table (movies2) and run:

```
insert into movies2(title, year) select title, year from movies

update m2
  set m2.genre = m1.genre
  from movies2 as m2
  inner join movies1 as m1 on m2.title = m1.title

insert into movies2(title, genre)
  select title, genre
  from movies1
  where title not in (select title from movies2)
```

Comment: The question is pretty clearly about MS Access, not MySQL (Access is mentioned in the title and the second sentence).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Um, yes, now it does. He just edited the post. It originally was tagged `mysql`.

Comment: I edited the post to remove the tag for mysql, but did not change the content of the question.  You can click on the edits and see that the question hasn't been edited since 5 minutes after it was posted (the first 5 minutes of edits aren't tracked).  Given the timing of your answer, it is possible that the OP edited the question since you saw it.  I would not downvote your answer, but there are others who might because it is about the wrong database.

Comment: This is what I wrote: "Is it mysql or ms-access? I'm assuming mysql here." Apparently, I **did** read it. It had conflicting information no matter who edited it.